# 'EntityMalformedException' after modifying '$form_state['values']'

Tags: 7, hooks

I have to replace some Arabic characters with Persian ones. I used `hook_form_alter()` and added my form submission callback as first one.

```
farsichar_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'farsichar_custom_submission');
}

function farsichar_custom_submission($form, &$form_state) {
  farsichar_replace($form_state['values']);
}
```

`farschar_replace()` is a recursive function which crawls in `$form_state['values']` and replaces the characters.

```
function farsichar_replace(&$value) {
  // $arabchar is an array of characters which I like to replace.
  // $farsichar is an array of substitutions.

  if (is_array($value) && empty($value)) {
    return;
  }
  if (!is_array($value)) {
    $value = str_replace($arabchar, $farsichar, $value);
    return;
  }

  $keys = array_keys($value);

  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $value[$key] = farsichar_replace($value[$key]);
  }
}
```

I get this error message every time I submit the form:

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node in `entity_extract_ids()` (line 7501 of includes/common.inc).

Where's this problem come from?